# Flask HTML Jinja2 url_for more than 1 '/'

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

```
{{url_for('image')}}
```

Will point to http://example.com/image

How can I generate a URL with more slashes? http://example.com/image/png/large

Answer (score 2):

Just discovered all I need to do is camelCase

```
{{url_for('imagePngLarge')}}
```